# Why Nuxt making multiple request for the "user" endpoint?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

There is an Express server and a Nuxt client. Nuxt version is 2.15.7.

Entire [auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh#options) configuration:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
auth: {
  plugins: [
    {
      src: '~/plugins/axios',
      ssr: true
    },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/auth'
    }
  ],
  cookie: {
    prefix: 'auth.',
    options: {
      path: '/',
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false
    }
  },
  localStorage: {
    prefix: 'auth.'
  },
  vuex: {
    namespace: 'auth'
  },
  strategies: {
    local: {
      scheme: 'refresh',
      token: {
        property: 'accessToken',
        maxAge: 900,
        global: true,
        name: 'Authorization',
        type: 'Bearer'
      },
      refreshToken: {
        property: 'refreshToken',
        data: 'refreshToken',
        maxAge: 5184000
      },
      user: {
        property: 'user',
        autoFetch: false
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: '/user/sign_in',
          method: 'post'
        },
        logout: {
          url: '/user/sign_out',
          method: 'delete'
        },
        refresh: {
          url: '/user/refresh',
          method: 'get'
        },
        user: {
          url: '/user/profile',
          method: 'get'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  redirect: {
    login: '/auth/sign_in',
    logout: '/',
    callback: '/auth/sign_in',
    home: '/'
  }
}
```

When I refresh the page in the browser, I see this in the browser log:

[image]

This message comes from here:

```
// plugins/axios.ts
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'

export default function ({ $axios, }: any) {
  $axios.onRequest((config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    console.log('Making request to ' + config.url)
  })
}
```

There are also two requests in the server logs. But in the first request I can get, for example, cookies, and in the second one comes this:

```
// console.log(req.cookies)

[Object: null prototype] {}
```

Can you please tell me why there are two requests?

Comment: Are you sure they are requests and not just the same request logged twice ? Check the Network Tab.

Comment: @BrahmaDev I see two requests in the server logs. The main problem is that this second request causes an error on the server, since the server does not see the cookies. In the first request, the server sees all the cookies, but in the second it does not.

Comment: What are the status codes of the 2 requests? Are you sure this is not a CORS issue?

Comment: Otherwise, it you arrive on the URL (not by client-side navigation so), it's legit that you do have a double fetch if your `target` is set to `server` (default value). You can alway set `fetchOnServer` to `false` if you want to disable this behavior https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch#options

Comment: @kissu first - 204, second - 200. I'm not convinced that the problem is CORS 

Comment: @kissu I can't figure out where exactly to use `fetchOnServer`? Inside the components I have no `/user/profile` requests. These requests are executed every time I refresh the page or sign in.

Comment: Which file is calling the `nuxt/auth` method? Do you have it in a middleware?

Comment: @kissu I have updated the original text of the question. The middleware is there (for guest), but I checked - it does not cause problems. It doesn't have any complicated logic, just `if (store.state.auth.loggedIn) {return redirect ('/')}`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by the back end returning this after sign in:

```json
{
  "is": 1
}
```

And should return this:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "is": 1
  }
}
```

After I added the "user" object, nuxt auth accepted the information and started working correctly.